# How to show upload progress using Expo FileSystem.uploadAsync

Tags: react-native, axios, expo, expo-file-system

I have a piece of code as below which uploads a simple file as binary utilizing **expo-file-system** and everything works fine.

```js
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

const res = await FileSystem.uploadAsync(uploadUrl, uri, {
  fieldName: 'file',
  httpMethod: 'PUT',
  uploadType: FileSystem.FileSystemUploadType.BINARY_CONTENT,
  headers: headers,
});
```

How to show the upload progress just like a simple axios upload progress?
In case the feature is not implemented how can I still upload a file as binary using `axios` to show the progress

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the documentation for [Expo FileSystem's uploadAsync](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemuploadasyncurl-fileuri-options), there does not appear to be a way to get upload progress.  You likely would need to choose another mechanism to upload ; use the FileSystem to injest the file's contents, then use another URL mechanism (e.g. onUploadProgress in axios's [Request Config](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config)) to upload the contents.

Comment: I have to upload my file as binary content. If I want to use `axios`, how should I convert the file content to binary (no multipart/form-data) utilizing `expo-file-system` or any other packages to achieve the axios upload progress?

Comment: What is the service that you are uploading to expecting?

Comment: Uploading directly to s3 with pre-signed link which is generated in backend

Comment: So what API are you planning on calling for uploading to S3?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the API is. The only thing that matters is how to upload **binary content** in `expo` utilizing `axios` to have the upload progress or get the upload progress somehow from `expo-file-system`

Comment: It does matter what the API is because that will dictate *how* you can pass the contents of a file to it.  A REST API is different than a binary API/SDK.  An API might dictate the format that content needs to be in (e.g. base64 encoded).  An API might dictate a set of calls you need to make, and in what order.  An API might be able to be given the file path so it can read the file itself.  So OF COURSE the API matters.  You are targetting the API.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem :)

```
const uploadTask = FileSystem.createUploadTask(crData.putUrl, media.path, {
    fieldName: 'file',
    httpMethod: 'PUT',
    uploadType: FileSystem.FileSystemUploadType.BINARY_CONTENT,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
    }
}, ({ totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend }) => {
    const progress = parseFloat((totalBytesSent / (totalBytesExpectedToSend || 1)).toFixed(2));
    setUploadProgress(progress);
});

const result = await uploadTask.uploadAsync();
```